# Apex variable shows as null

Tags: apex, apex-variable

I have the following code below.  The field **generatedToken** gets populated in getTokenFromA(), but when I access it in PutA() it is null.  I have tried defining it as just static (without public) and received the same results.  Any help in defining this correctly would be appreciated.

```
public class OurCallout {
    public static String generatedToken {set; get;}
    static String errorMessage {set; get;}
    static String TimelineResponse {set; get;}
    
    @future(callout = true)
    
    public static void getTokenFromA() {    
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('hard_coded_client_id' + ':' + 'hard_coded_client_key')));
        req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setEndpoint('https://ourdomain.com/token');
        req.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials');

        Http http = new Http();
    
        try{
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            JSONParser objParse = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
            while (objParse.nextToken() != null) 
            {
                if (objParse.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && objParse.getText() == 'access_token')
                {                               
                     objParse.nextToken();
                    generatedToken = objParse.getText();
                }
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception ex){
            errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
            System.debug('Exception :' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

        public static void PutA() {
            getTokenFromA(); // Generate new access token before calling bellow API
            if(generatedToken == null ) {
                TimelineResponse = 'Error while generating token, so unable to get messages. Check your debug log.';
                return;
            }
            try{
                HttpRequest objReq = new HttpRequest();
               objReq.setEndpoint('https://ourdomain.com/ourendpoint');
                objReq.setMethod('POST');
                objReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'hard_coded_token');
                objReq.setBody('{"record_id": 5640,"Email": "younotthererorhere@there.org"}');
                Http objHttp = new Http();
                HTTPResponse objRes = objHttp.send(objReq);
                TimelineResponse = objRes.getBody();
                if(String.isBlank(TimelineResponse)){
                    TimelineResponse = objRes.toString();
                }
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {  errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
                System.debug('ExceptionP :' + ex.getMessage());
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your try/catch blocks are only making it harder for you to detect any errors that are happening. You should remove them and let the exceptions be uncaught.

Comment: @DerekF I will take them out...but I do not think that is what the issue is here.  genereatedToken gets a value in getTokenFromA().  I had a debug statement there and verified it contained data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getTokenFromA` is marked with `@future` it will not run in the current transaction that calls `PutA` but will run sometime later. So `generatedToken` will always be null.

You will need to restructure your logic e.g. make the second HTTP call from inside the `getTokenFromA` method.

Comment: Thank you.  I will make this one method instead of two.  The examples I found online had the two methods - but as you indicated I do not actually need them.

Answer (score 3):

Future methods are called asynchronously. This means that `getTokenFromA()` will not start until `putA()` has finished, and in fact, won't even be in the same logical transaction as the original method call. I don't see a reason to use @future for `getTokenFromA()` (without more context, this is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)), but given what is in the question, you should remove `@future(callout=true)` from your code.

Comment: Thank you.  I am doing a call out from a trigger to this class - everything I read and found indicated I need the @future statement.